# Filter grouped data by the top X groups based on certain variable

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr

I want to filter a grouped dataset by a certain number of users exhibiting the largest value in a certain variable. The value of this variable does not vary within the groups.

Simple example: Imagine 3 indiviudals and we observe the total number of their visits.

```
da = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), n_visits = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1))
da
  id n_visits
1  1        3
2  1        3
3  1        3
4  2        2
5  2        2
6  2        2
7  3        1
8  3        1
9  3        1
```

Now I want to select the 2 users with the largest number of visits, which are users with ids "1" and "2" in my example.

I tried the "top_n" function, but it outputs the data of all three indiviudals.

```
da %>% group_by(id) %>%
   top_n(2, n_visits)

# A tibble: 9 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id n_visits
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        3
2     1        3
3     1        3
4     2        2
5     2        2
6     2        2
7     3        1
8     3        1
9     3        1
```

The output I expect is:

```
         id n_visits
      <dbl>    <dbl>
    1     1        3
    2     1        3
    3     1        3
    4     2        2
    5     2        2
    6     2        2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using **data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
da = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), n_visits = c(3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1))
setDT(da)
merge(da, unique(da)[order(-n_visits)][1:2], all.y = T, by = c("id", "n_visits"))
#>    id n_visits
#> 1:  1        3
#> 2:  1        3
#> 3:  1        3
#> 4:  2        2
#> 5:  2        2
#> 6:  2        2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks,t works on the example, on my real data it outputs:

Fehler in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 17557500 rows; more than 9252065 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: your error on my computer is not reproducible `n <- 200
x <- 1:100000
y <- 100000:1
dt <- data.table(id = rep(x, each = n), n_visits = rep(y, each = n))
nrow(dt)

merge(dt, unique(dt)[order(-n_visits)][1:2], all.y = T, by = c("id", "n_visits"))`
maybe more experienced data.table users will answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with join:

```
inner_join(da, da %>% unique() %>% top_n(2, n_visits))
# Joining, by = c("id", "n_visits")
#   id n_visits
# 1  1        3
# 2  1        3
# 3  1        3
# 4  2        2
# 5  2        2
# 6  2        2
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. My data is quite large and it's running long when using your inner_join solution (...not finished yet) - is there a solution that works faster?

Comment: @Scijens, if your data size is large, using `data.table` should be faster as in Yuriy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
da %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(n_visits))) %>% 
     filter(rank %in% c(1,2)) %>% 
         select(-rank)
  id n_visits
1  1        3
2  1        3
3  1        3
4  2        2
5  2        2
6  2        2
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
subset(
  da,
  n_visits %in% head(sort(unique(n_visits), decreasing = TRUE), 2)
)
```

gives

```
  id n_visits
1  1        3
2  1        3
3  1        3
4  2        2
5  2        2
6  2        2
```